# Sticky footer covers bottom of body content

Tags: html, css, footer, overlap, sticky

I've added a sticky footer, and I'm having trouble getting it to not cover the body content in Safari.
Chrome and FF work fine, I've added a bottom-margin to the body to counter the height of the sticky footer. Why doesn't the same work in Safari?

Here is the page in question... I don't know which parts of the code to paste here, sorry...

http://go.datis.com/2019summit_agenda

I'd like the body content to have a margin between it and the sticky footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add

```
    padding-bottom: 200px
```

to your events class

Comment: That worked, than you very much! I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You've got an inline `height` style on `div class="large-header" id="large-header"` that appears to be conflicting with a max-height style on line 416 of your stylesheet.